# Javascript Timer not Updating

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I know a million JavaScript timer questions have been asked already, but I can't figure this one out.

The `#drive` element is updated the first time (to `0`) but not after that, as if either `setTimeout()` is not working or `this.count++` is not working. Anyone know why this isn't working?

Thanks...

```
var timer = {
    timerRunning: false,
    count: 0,
    delay: 1000,

    tick: function() {
        $("#drive").html(this.count);
        this.count++;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (this.timerRunning)
                this.tick();
        }, this.delay);
    },

    start: function() {
        this.timerRunning = true;
        this.tick();
    },

    stop: function() {
        this.timerRunning = false;
    }
};

timer.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `this` inside your `setTimeout()` callback is no longer your timer object (it will be the `window` object).  That's why it isn't working.

You can fix it like this by setting a closure variable to your object and using that instead:

```
tick: function() {
    $("#drive").html(this.count);
    this.count++;
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (self.timerRunning)
            self.tick();
    }, this.delay);
},
```

Comment: Wow, I even tried window.setTimeout() but didn't think to do this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The callback is bound to a different this variable. Here is a workaround:

```
    tick: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("#drive").html(this.count);
        this.count++;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (self.timerRunning)
                self.tick();
        }, this.delay);
    }
```